# Haproxy userlist and allow ip without password

Tags: linux, haproxy

How to add haproxy ip address that was not asked for a password when I use the userlist?

```
userlist user
        user user insecure-password password
        allow ip 1.1.1.1 [example]
```

analogously to auth basic in apache

```
AuthType Basic 
AuthUserFile /www/.site_htpasswd 
AuthName "xxx" 
require valid-user 
Allow from 1.2.3.4
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use haproxy ACLs:

```
frontend example-frontend
     acl ip_whitelist src 1.1.1.1
     acl auth_ok http_auth(user)
     # require authentication when not in whitelist and not authenticated
     http-request auth if !ip_whitelist !auth_ok
```